# Manga where the merchant son's plan is to heal damaged slaves

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga, isekai

Trying to find a manga i saw a while back.  The son of a merchant has this plan to buy cheap damaged slaves and heal them using magic.  I think the first two slaves he rescues are a female centaur & female harpy.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, what colour was the protagonist's hair?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 7):

I believe this is ***[Living in Another World by Taking Commissions ~A Relaxing and Comfy Life of The Restoration Magician's Staffing Agency~](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/1k1szr7/isekai-de-uwamae-hanete-ikiteiku-saisei-mahotsukai-no-yuru-fuwa-jinzai-haken-seikatsu)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> **A company drone who died from overworking was reincarnated as Sawadi, the third son of a merchant in a different world.** His specialty is restoration magic and support magic. He used his cheat skills to come up with a new model of business. **He decided to use his restoration magic to cure cheap slaves and make them earn money.**
>
> Although his earnings are steadily increasing, he also has to suffer its consequence of his work load also getting increased... Will Sawadi ever be able to live leisurely without working? The beginning of this lazy and relaxing fantasy, is starting here!

The synopsis fits the general premise, and the MC does buy a female centaur and harpy in the first chapter.

[image]

[image]